# imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php

I try to upload  multiple files  to  my bucket earlier it worked well but now I try to resize and compress the image before upload, it throws error `imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given` here is the code :

```
foreach($_FILES as  $ind => $filegroup){

$count=0;
foreach($_FILES[$ind]['name']as  $actfile){

                
                $tmp=$_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name'][$count];


                $count=$count + 1;
$newind= str_replace('_',' ',$ind);
                $filenamenew= $insertedids[0].$newind."_".$count.".jpg";
                $temp='menu_images/'.$filenamenew; 



$im = imagecreatetruecolor(700, 700);
$bg = imagecolorallocate ( $im, 255, 255, 255 );
imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,700,700,$bg);


$max_width=700;
 $max_height= 700;

 $width = imagesx($tmp);

    $height = imagesy($tmp);

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }


$im2 = imagescale($tmp, $width, $height);

imagecopy($im, $im2, (imagesx($im)/2)-(imagesx($im2)/2), (imagesy($im)/2)-(imagesy($im2)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2));


imagejpeg($im, NULL , 70);
```

I am trying to upload this final `$im` to bucket , I have already installed gd library in my cent os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem was posting `sourcefile` to s3 bucket I changed that to `body` , also I changed my php settings to allow file upload till 5 mb

Here is the solution:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(700, 700);
$bg = imagecolorallocate ( $im, 255, 255, 255 );
imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,700,700,$bg);



list( $width, $height , $image_type ) = getimagesize($tmp);

$max_width=700;
 $max_height= 700;

 

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }


switch ($image_type)
    {
        case 1: $im3 = imagecreatefromgif($tmp); break;
        case 2: $im3 = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);  break;
        case 3: $im3 = imagecreatefrompng($tmp); break;
        default: return '';  break;
    }

$im2 = imagescale($im3, $width, $height);


imagecopy($im, $im2, (imagesx($im)/2)-(imagesx($im2)/2), (imagesy($im)/2)-(imagesy($im2)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2));



$imgdata = image_data($im);
function image_data($gdimage)
{
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($gdimage,NULL,70);
    return(ob_get_clean());
}
```

And while uploading to bucket

```
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'yourbucket',
    'Key'    => 'filename',
    'Body' => $imgdata 
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`imagesx()` expects an image resource as parameter, returned by one of the image creation functions for example `imagecreatetruecolor()`. If you need the height or width of of an image, you can use `getimagesize()` like below.

```
list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( 'filepath' );
```

Comment: New error is   `getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty`

Comment: aren't you taking file path in `$tmp` ?

Comment: what are you storing in $tmp ?

Comment: it is the image which i want to upload

Comment: try using `$_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name']` instead of $tmp in getimagesize function

Comment: both are the same so why redundant

Comment: problem was the size of the file it was from dslr hence above 3 mb , thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
foreach($_FILES[$ind]['name'] as $fid => $actfile){ // add $fid in here!
   ...
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmp=$_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name'][$fid]);
   echo "width: $width; height: $height<br />\n";
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: impossible... you got to be doing something wrong... try `print_r($_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name']);`, what  do you get?

Comment: Earlier everything uploaded to my bucket , so there should not be any problem in file handling part

Comment: problem was the size of the file it was from dslr hence above 3 mb , thanks for your time